# How to get all classes in iModel.js

Tags: imodeljs

I am working on an [iModel.js](https://imodeljs.github.io/iModelJs-docs-output/) project that involves an OpenPlant schema. The iModel file has been uploaded to the [iModelHub](https://imodeljs.github.io/iModelJs-docs-output//learning/imodelhub/) using a MicroStation bridge. I have been able to successfully;

1. Get an IMS access token
2. Open an iModelDb by passing in the access token, the CONNECT project id and the iModel id
3. Run ECSql queries against the iModelDb object using the [executeQuery](https://imodeljs.github.io/iModelJs-docs-output/reference/imodeljs-backend/imodels/imodeldb/executequery/) command.

I am trying to get a list of all the Process Piping and Process Equipment classes and display them in a pane. I am doing a `SELECT * FROM Bis.Element GROUP BY ECClassId`. This gives me a list of all the elements and corresponding classIDs but, this list seems to be incomplete. I only get 4 process equipment classes (`CentrifugalPump`, `Drum`, `Vessel`, and `Tank`) and 5 process piping classes (`ConcentricPipeReducer`, `Nozzle`, `GateValve`, `Pipeline`, `PipeRun`, and `ThreeWayValve`).

How do I get a list of all the classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are only querying the instance data of the iModel. The resulting limited list of classes contains the actual elements that exist in the iModel file. The file contains physical (or functional) elements for only those 4 process equipment class and 5 process piping class types, which is why those are the ones you see.

Luckily, each iModel file has an `ECDbMeta ECSchema`. An `ECDbMeta ECSchema` is a schema that provides information ABOUT the schemas themselves (that in turn give the instance data its meaning). All class definitions inside the schemas exist in the iModel as their own separate dataset. This information exists for the sole purpose making the context of the instance data portable.

For example, when you do a `SELECT * FROM Bis.Element`, you get a list of all the `Bis.Elements` that currently exist within the iModel. As you noticed, all these elements have their own class Ids. A `Nozzle` is just another `Bis.Element` but it is of the `Nozzle` subclass type that is defined in the `ProcessPipingFunctional` schema.

You can query the `ECDbMeta ECSchema`, to get a list of all classes defined within Process Piping and Piping equipment schemas.  Here are some sample `SELECT` statements:

> "SELECT Name AS name, Alias AS alias, ECInstanceId AS id FROM ECDbMeta.ECSchemaDef ORDER BY Name"

The above statement will give you a list of all the schemas imported into the iModel you are querying. Once you get this list, you can get the `schema.id` for the process and piping schemas you are looking for. You can then use those ids to run the following query:

> "SELECT Name AS name FROM ECDbMeta.ECClassDef WHERE ECClassDef.Schema.Id=? ORDER BY Name"

This query will give you the list of all the classes defined within those schemas.

For more information on the metaschemas: https://imodeljs.github.io/iModelJs-docs-output/learning/ecdbmeta.ecschema/